# Partial View | Not Loading CSS

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am having an issue with my addSale function,  I can get it to load the content but it does not carry the CSS from my Main Template CSS link through to my jQuery Colorbox pop up box,

How could I make my partial view load the required CSS document?

**Main Template:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]><html lang=en-us class="no-js ie6"><![endif]--> 
<!--[if IE 7 ]><html lang=en-us class="no-js ie7"><![endif]--> 
<!--[if IE 8 ]><html lang=en-us class="no-js ie8"><![endif]--> 
<!--[if (gte IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--> <html lang=en-us class=no-js> <!--<![endif]--> 
<head>
    <title><?php echo str_replace(".php","",ucfirst(basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']))); ?> : Nationwide Housemovers</title>
    <link href="<?php echo base_url()?>includes/css/adminstyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <link href="<?php echo base_url()?>includes/css/colorbox.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?=base_url()?>includes/css/validationEngine.jquery.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url() ?>includes/js/ckedit/ckeditor.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url() ?>includes/js/shiv.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div id ="wrapper">

        <div id="header">

            <div class="companyName"></div>
            <div class="companyQuote"></div>

        </div>
        <div id ="leftCol">
 <nav>
        <ul>
        <?php if($this->session->userdata('logged_in')): ?>
            <li><?php echo anchor('admin/dashboard', 'Dashboard');?></li>
            <li><a>Edit Pages</a>
                <?php if(is_array($cms_pages)): ?>
                <ul>
                    <?php foreach($cms_pages as $page): ?>
                <li><a href="<?=base_url();?>admin/editpage/index/<?= $page->id ?>/<?php echo url_title($page->name,'dash', TRUE); ?>"><?=$page->name?></a></li>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>

                </ul> <!-- UL Close -->
                <?php endif; ?>
            </li> <!-- Edit Close -->

            <li><a href="gallery">Gallery</a>
                <ul>
                <li><?php echo anchor('admin/addimage','Add Image');?></li>
                <li><?php echo anchor('admin/deleteimage','Delete Image');?></li>
                <li><?php echo anchor('admin/imagecaption','Edit Caption');?></li>
                </ul>
            </li> <!-- Gallery Close -->

            <li><a href="sales">Sales</a>
            <ul>
                <li><?php echo anchor('admin/addsale','Add Sale');?></li>
                <li><a>Edit Sale</a>
                            <?php if(is_array($sales_pages)): ?>
                                    <ul>
                                        <?php foreach($sales_pages as $sale): ?>
                                        <li><a href="<?=base_url();?>admin/editsale/index/<?=$sale->id?>/<?php echo url_title($sale->name,'dash', TRUE); ?>"><?=$sale->name?></a></li>
                                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                                    </ul>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                                </li><!-- LI Edit Sale Close -->
                <li><?php echo anchor('admin/deletesale','Delete Sale');?></li>
            </ul><!-- UL Close -->

            <li><?php echo anchor('admin/home/logout','Log Out');?></li>
        <?php else: ?>
        <?php redirect('admin/home'); ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </ul>
 </nav>
        </div><!--leftCol End -->

        <section id="content">
            <h1><?=$title?></h1>
            <?=$content?>

        </section>

        <div class="clear"></div>

        <footer>
         <p>LTD <?php echo date('Y'); ?></p>
        </footer>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url() ?>includes/js/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="<?= base_url() ?>includes/jquery.colorbox-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script src="<?= base_url() ?>includes/js/jquery.colorbox.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script src="<?= base_url() ?>includes/js/jquery.validationEngine-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script src="<?= base_url() ?>includes/js/jquery.validationEngine.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("a[rel='newSale']").colorbox({width:"80%", height:"80%", iframe:true});
        $("a[rel='editsale']").colorbox({width:"50%", inline:true, href:"#addSale"});
        $("#pageEdit").validationEngine();
        $("#addImage").validationEngine();
        $("#addSale").validationEngine();
        $("#editSale").validationEngine();
            $('#captionSelect').change(function(){
                var id = $(this).val();
                var caption = $('#captionOption_' + id).html();
                var thumbname = $('#captionOption_' + id).attr('title');
                $('#captionInput').val(caption);
                $('#preview').attr('src', '/includes/uploads/gallery/thumbs/' + thumbname);
                alert('/path/to/pictures/' + thumbname + '.jpg');
            });
        });
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Sales View:**

```
<div id="newSale">
    <a href="sales/addSale" rel="newSale">Add Sale</a>
</div>

<?php if($sales_pages): ?>
        <?php foreach($sales_pages as $sale): ?>
    <div id ="salesItem">
    <img class="thumbnail" src="<?=base_url()?>includes/uploads/sales/thumbs/<?=$sale->thumbname?>" alt="<?=$sale->name?>"/>

    <div class="items"><a href="deletesale/delete/<?=$sale->id?>">Delete</a> | <a href="#"rel="editsale" >Edit Sale</a> | <a href="#">Images</a></div>
</div>

        <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**Sales Controller:**

```
class Sales extends CI_Controller { 

    function __construct(){ 
    parent::__construct(); 
    $this->load->library('user_agent');
    } 
    function index() { 
    if(!$this->session->userdata('logged_in')) { 
        redirect('admin/home'); 
    } 
    // Main Page Data 
    $data['sales_pages'] = $this->sales_model->getSalesPages();
    $data['cms_pages'] = $this->navigation_model->getCMSPages();
    $data['title'] = 'Sales';
    $data['content'] = $this->load->view('admin/sales', $data, TRUE); 
    $this->load->view('admintemplate', $data);
}

 function addSale(){
    $this->load->view('admin/testview',  TRUE);
 }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you use an iframe, i think you should build a proper html document, complete with its own stylesheet.